# onPress Handler of a button updates the state but screen goes blank

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native and trying to build a todo app. In the code below, I have two useState hooks one for keeping track of what user enters and `allTodo` one for keeping track of all the todos to be rendered, also I'm using FlatList for rendering todos but when I submit the todo, the screen just goes blank and nothing  appears again until I refresh it again. Also I'm testing the app on chrome by selecting a device in it. could that be a problem? Please let me know what the problem is. Code is below:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [allTodos, setAllTodos] = useState(["a", "b"]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setAllTodos(allTodos.push(todo));
    setTodo("");
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{todo}</Text>
      <Text>Todo: </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="E.g. Buy eggs"
        onChangeText={(val) => setTodo(val)}
      />
      <Button title="Add Todo" onPress={handleSubmit} />

      <FlatList
        data={allTodos}
        // keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FBF4E9",
    alignItems: "center",
    // justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  item: {
    marginTop: 24,
    padding: 30,
    backgroundColor: "pink",
    fontSize: 24,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: 24,
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#777",
    padding: 8,
    margin: 10,
    width: 200,
  },
});
```

This is what it looks before submitting the todo:
[image: image before submitting the todo]

Image after I submit it:

[image: image of the screen after todo is submitted]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mutate state. In your `handleSubmit`  function, you are mutating the state  `allTodos`.

simply change your `handleSubmit` function to,

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {

  const currentTodos = [...allTodos];
  currentTodos.push(todo);
  setAllTodos(currentTodos);
  setTodo('');
};
```

Also you might want to pass the `value` prop of `TextInput` as `todo`.

Check this [Live Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/so_todo) to see it in action.